# Call to a possibly undefined method setSelection through a reference with static type SelectionManager

Tags: tlf

I'm working with an TLF example (older version) and I'm getting errors when I try to run it:

1061: Call to a possibly undefined method setSelection through a reference with static type flashx.textLayout.edit:ISelectionManager.

```
_textFlow.interactionManager.setSelection(0,0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an updated example [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/flex/tlf/trunk/sdk/samples/flex/SimpleEditor/src/SimpleEditorPanel.mxml) that contains some of the names of the classes that have been renamed:

- TextFilter => TextConverter
- ChangeElementIdOperation => ApplyElementIDOperation
- DisplayObjectContainerController => ContainerController
- ChangeElementStyleNameOperation => ApplyElementStyleNameOperation
- flashx.textLayout.BuildInfo.kBuildNumber => TextLayoutVersion.getVersionString(TextLayoutVersion.CURRENT_VERSION)
- textFlow.interactionManager.setSelection(0,0) =>_textFlow.interactionManager.setRange(0,0)
- e.selectedElementRange.paragraphFormat =>
      var selectionState:SelectionState = e.selectionState;
      var selectedElementRange:ElementRange = ElementRange.createElementRange(selectionState.textFlow,
  selectionState.absoluteStart, selectionState.absoluteEnd);
- textFlow.computedTextLayoutFormat => textFlow.computedFormat

I found an updated example of this project on the [Apache Flex](http://flex.apache.org/installer.html) SDK in the directory flex-tlf/sdk/samples/flex/SimpleEditorWithCSS.